# How to make a shortcut/script that checks and toggles screen orientation in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, screen, orientation

I have a screen with pivot functionality, and I'd very much like just one shortcut/launcher on my desktop that toggles between two orientations. In my case that would be the two commands:

xrandr -o left
  xrandr -o normal

How can I make this a shortcut that checks which orientation is used and make it take appropriate action? I use nvidia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the script mentioned at [this blog post](http://blog.gammal.org/2006/06/screen-rotation-using-xrandr.html). If it works, just save it somewhere like /usr/local/bin/toggle_xrandr.sh (make sure you do chmod +x on it), and then create a new shortcut on your desktop or panel pointing to the script.